# Wrong data array when reading a text file in Octave

Tags: octave

I want to read a text file, which has two columns and that looks as follows.

```
-0,090  26,295
-0,342  26,294
-0,594  26,294
-0,846  26,295
-1,098  26,294
-1,368  26,296
-1,620  26,296
-1,872  26,296
```

I'm using the following code to read it and to create the data array.

```
filename = 'C:\Users\file location\test.txt';   
delimiter = '\t';   
formatSpec = '%s%s%[^\n\r]';
fileID = fopen(filename,'rt'); 
dataArray = textscan(fileID, formatSpec, 'Delimiter', delimiter, 'ReturnOnError', false, 'EndOfLine', '\r\n');
fclose(fileID);
```

What I get is an array like this.

```
dataArray =
{
  [1,1] =
  {
    [1,1] = -0,090
    [2,1] = -0,594
    [3,1] = -1,098
    [4,1] = -1,620
    [5,1] =
  }

  [1,2] =
  {
    [1,1] = 26,295
    [2,1] = 26,294
    [3,1] = 26,294
    [4,1] = 26,296
    [5,1] =
  }

  [1,3] =
  {
    [1,1] = -0,342      26,294
    [2,1] = -0,846      26,295
    [3,1] = -1,368      26,296
    [4,1] = -1,872      26,296
    [5,1] =
  }
   }
```

So apparently Octave takes only every second row of my original columns to create my array and combines the skipped values to a third column.

What I actually expect is an array like this.

```
dataArray =
{
  [1,1] =
  {
    [1,1] = -0,090
    [2,1] = -0,342
    [3,1] = -0,594
    [4,1] = -0,846
    [5,1] = -1,098
    [6,1] = -1,368
    [7,1] = -1,620
    [8,1] = -1,872
  }

  [1,2] =
  {
    [1,1] = 26,295
    [2,1] = 26,294
    [3,1] = 26,294
    [4,1] = 26,295
    [5,1] = 26,294
    [6,1] = 26,296
    [7,1] = 26,296
    [8,1] = 26,296
  }
}
```

I assume it's a problem with formatSpec. Is it somehow possible to adjust my code so that I get my expected array?

Comment: For me (Windows 10, Octave 5.1.0), `dataArray = textscan(fileID, '%s%s')` does the job!?

Comment: Yes, thanks it works. Apparently, I was thinking too complicated.

Answer (score 1):

The main issue here is that commas are used instead of dots in your file.

My advice would be to forget about elaborate textscanning, and simply preprocess your files instead, to replace the offending commas with dots. This can be done easily on a linux terminal, however it's easy enough to do in octave as well if you prefer, e.g.

```
% Read in file as string
Data_str = fileread('test.txt');

% Correct commas to dots
CorrectedData_str = strrep( Data_str, ',' , '.' );

% Write data back to a file (I'm surprised there's no equivalent "filewrite" ...)
f = fopen( 'corrected_test.txt', 'w' );
fprintf(f, CorrectedData_str);
fclose(f);
```

Once you have preprocessed all your data, importing is then as simple as:

```
MyData = importdata('corrected_test.txt');
```

Comment: I replace the commas with dots later in my script, but thanks anyway :)